# Send javascript to footer with Smarty

Tags: php, javascript, build, smarty

Problem: neat loading of javascript files in footer. 
Question: do you have any method or do you know a method to do this ellegantly with smarty?

I can imagine assigning arrays at tpl runtime and make a foreach in footer.tpl that neatly renders them. I can aslo imagine a whole helper or object in that matter.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you suggested is actually how I do it. And I'm quite satisfied that way.

PHP:

```
$loadJSFiles = array();
$loadJSFiles[] = 'file1.js';
$loadJSFiles[] = 'file2.js';
$smarty->assign('loadJSFiles', $loadJSFiles);
```

Template:

```
{foreach $loadJSFiles as $val}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{$val}"></script>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean we load JS files from the controller? I do not find it really attractive in terms of MVC'ness. What I was saying was that in the tpl file I would do the assign...

Comment: Well, it works good enough for me :-) Maybe for your project annother solution fits better...